# Auto logout in yii

Tags: php, yii

How to do auto logout after some minute if the user is idle 
I am using yii framework.

I can set logout time under user component in main.php 
but the question is how to check the user is idle?

Comment: its yii2, but can you give idea for both yii1 and 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['lastpageview']) && (time()-(int)Yii::app()->request->cookies['lastpageview']->value > 3600))
{
    //logout
}
else
{
    Yii::app()->request->cookies['lastpageview'] = new CHttpCookie('lastpageview', time());
}
```

where 3600 is the max number or seconds allowed

Answer (score 0):

For Yii 1.xx CWebUser has property authTimeout.
From off documentation:

> authTimeout - timeout in seconds after which user is logged out if
>   inactive.

Set it propety into main config:

```
...
'components' => array(
    ....
    'user' => array(
        'authTimeout' => 60*60*5,
    ), 
    ....
),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDbHttpSession component to make it work:

```
'components' => array(
   'session' => array(
      'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
      'timeout' => 1,
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        //'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'enableSession' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 900,
    ],
```

its working fine to me!(YII 2.0)
time out session after 15 min if request is come after 15 min then auto redirect to site/login page.

Answer (score 0):

Could add a simple js script that occasionally pings the server to check if session is still active.

1. Set the session timeout as mentioned by the other answers

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [        
        'authTimeout' => 1800, //30min
    ],
    'session' => [
        'timeout' => 1800, //30mins
    ],
],
```

2. Crete a controller action that you can call (via ajax) that would return the user status

```
public function actionCheckSession()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ['active' => !\Yii::$app->user->isGuest];
}
```

3. the js code that occassionally checks the status (as long as browser tab is open). If session has timed out, it would redirect the browser to the login page.

```
<script>
setInterval(() => fetch('/site/check-session').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
    if (!data.active) window.location = '/site/login';
}), 60000); //Check every minute or your desired value
</script>
```